# How Do You Reset Validated Fields Using FormStrap.IO/Bootstrap Validator When Click Event is Outside Form?

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a form that collects flight information from a user.  The user can enter in their departure date, departure time, and departure location along with their return date, return time, and return location.  There's a simple radio button selection outside my form that allows a user to toggle between round-trip flights (default) and one-way.  If the user clicks one-way, the return time and date are disabled and hidden using JQuery.

I'm using FormStrapValidaton.IO/Bootstrap Validator and I've discovered that if I enter in an invalid field for the return date, then switch the flight from round-trip to one-way the error doesn't reset and I can't submit the form.  I've looked at http://formvalidation.io/examples/clearing-field-when-clicking-icon/ and clearing the field; but, can't figure out how to call this from outside the form when someone clicks the radio button.  Anyone know how I can call the http://formvalidation.io/api/#reset-field function for an object outside the form (or a way to do it inside the form validation logic)?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this.

I think the key is when outside of the form functions, you have to make sure you are dealing with jQuery objects.

```
$('#bookingForm').data('formValidation').resetField($('#returnDate'));
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I searched everywhere trying to find a way to do this and your answer worked! By any chance would you know how to make it work for 2 or more IDs? I tried this but it didn't work: `$('#formID').data('formValidation').resetField($('#element1,#element2'));`

Comment: I think the api only allows a single field http://formvalidation.io/api/#reset-field.

You'd need to get the elements first, then loop over them resetting them.

Answer (score 0):

try this will work, you should add second parameter, its Boolean [from plugin website](http://formvalidation.io/api/#reset-field)

If true, the method resets field value to empty or remove checked/selected    attribute (for radio and checkbox).

```
 var fv = $('#formId').data('formValidation');
  fv.resetField('#element', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://formvalidation.io/examples/modal/

```
$('#loginForm').formValidation('resetForm', true);
```